# How to use custom cultures?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, globalization

One of our clients requested that some terminology we're using should be changed according to their needs. That means changing a bunch of labels in forms and user messages. Our application is developed as multi-language application so everything is in resource files.

To solve this need I've decided to create a custom culture. I have created hr-HR-HP from standard hr-HR language. I did some tests and everything worked fine.

However, in our project, our third party components break down with the following exception

```
CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: culture
4096 (0x1000) is an invalid culture identifier.
```

Google says that this happens when CultureInfo is created via LCID and that is not supported for custom cultures. So, to avoid this i set Culture parameters as follows:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("hr-HR");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("hr-HR-HP");
```

Great, the error is gone and forms read their resources as expected. However, now ResourceManager is the problem. It's using hr satellite assembly instead of hr-HR-HP one. I use ResourceManager to read the user messages from satellite assemblies.

Any suggestions? Is it possible to specify which language I want for ResourceManager? Should I try some other approach?

Comment: Please consider using the BCP47 naming convention: hr-HR-x-HP would be better.

Comment: Never heard of BCP47. I'll look it up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I was so close to the answer. Just a little more googling reveals that I can specify what culture I want in ResourceManager.GetString() method.